# Controlled impedance traces necessary between line driver and series termination resistor?

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, impedance-matching

I'm designing a line driver circuit with the SN74BCT25244 chip. The chip has a rise time of ~10 ns into an open circuit based on my own scope testing, but we are only wanting to drive the signal at a frequency of around 10 kHz max.  The circuit goes to a co-ax connector and drives a 50 Ohm cable, connected to a 50 Ohm terminated device. Here's what the series connections of the circuit looks like on my board layout:

line-driver IC -> 24 Ohm resistor -> some cct protection elements (connected parallel, to GND) -> 22 Ohm resistor -> fuse -> coax connector

The total distance from line driver output pin to co-ax connector is about 1.1" (28 mm).

My question is: will I need to use controlled impedance routing on this design from the line driver to all of my other circuit elements and on to the connector?

I'm thinking even if I do, it will be screwed up by the varying widths of the resistors and fuse. Since I have about 50 ohms of series resistance from the line driver output to the co-ax connector, am I OK to use any trace width?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are still designing, and have not yet built boards, then your best bet is to just spend the extra penny for a ceramic capacitor to slow the rise time.  This is going to be much cheaper than telling the board house that you will need controlled impedance.  Otherwise just use a driver with a slower rise time.

Comment: It's one thing to have 'controlled impedance' on the board, but what are you going to control the impedance to? What is the ideal impedance to have on the driver to 24 ohms, the 24 ohms to protection devices, the protection to the 22 ohms, the 22 ohms to the connector, and most importantly, why?

Answer (score 1):

The 10 ns rise time you mentioned seems rather slow for a part that specs the prop times as 6 ns (max), and 1 ns (min).  The data sheet does not give a rise/fall time spec, so let's use the prop time as a surrogate for rise/fall time.  That means we need to design the interfaces to properly handle a 1 ns rise or fall time.

1 ns in a typical board material translates to 0.5 feet, or 6 inches, assuming 2 ns/foot prop time in the board.  Any interconnect length greater than 10% of this length needs to be controlled impedance.  That means that any trace longer than 0.6" needs to be controlled impedance.

This is critical for clocks and other edge sensitive signals.  If it's a data line you could probably cheat a bit on the 10% rule, up it to 20% (which would give you a bit more ringing, undershoot, or overshoot, which would mean 1.2" max interconnect length before you would have to impedance match.

Note, most PWB vendors do 50 ohm trace impedances as a matter of routine.  If you just specify 50 ohm (single ended) impedance +/- 10%, you should be fine.

**EDIT 1**

One more thing.  You should take your post-route PWB information (stackup, trace width/thickness/length, etc) and import them into you favorite SI tool, like Hyperlynx Board Sim (or Line Sim) and do the SI analysis.

**EDIT 2**

You also might want to look at the answers on this thread:

[Does matching impedance connectors matter in non-RF signals? Why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511980/does-matching-impedance-connectors-matter-in-non-rf-signals-why/511998#511998)